# how to custom map xml to classes in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to process the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<operation name="GET_NOTES">
  <result>
    <status>Success</status>
    <message>Notes details fetched successfully</message>
  </result>
<Details>
  <Notes>
    <Note URI="http://something/24/notes/302/">
      <parameter>
        <name>ispublic</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <name>notesText</name>
        <value>Note added to the request</value>
      </parameter>
      ...
    </Note>
    ...
  </Notes>
<Details>
</operation>
```

This has lots of useless stuff, so I'm trying to map into something like:

```
public class Notes {
  public List<Note> notes;
}

public class Note {
  public String notesText; //value of parameter with name notesText
  public Boolean isPublic; //value of parameter with name ispublic
}
```

Is this possible with JAXB, and how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

JAXB simply ignores the xmlelement that are not present in your bean. Alternatively, annotated the field with @XmlTransient instead of @XmlElement, and it will also be skipped.

In your case you need to write three classes i.e. Notes, note and parameter.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Notes")
public class Notes {
  public List<Note> notes;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Note")
public class Note {
 public parameter param;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="parameter")
public class parameter {
  public String name; //value of parameter with name notesText
  public Boolean value; //value of parameter with name ispublic
}
```

Comment: will notesText contain the string that is in the value tag inside parameter?